# silverlight MatchTimeoutInMilliseconds bug : resolve DomainServiceClientCodeGenerator

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, ria

Silverlight 5
.Net Framework 4

I am trying to implement a workaround for the recent bug in the RIA code generator
**"MatchTimeoutInMilliseconds could not be found"** 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1988437/generated-code-for-silverlight-references-matchtimeoutinmilliseconds-which-does-not-exist

I'm trying to use the workaround by **Lazebnyy**, But I can't seem to get **DomainServiceClientCodeGenerator** to resolve.

Lazebnyy writes:

> Install RIAServices.T4 from Nuget in the WebProejct or a Class Library
>   that will contain the the code generation classes. PM> Install-Package
>   RIAServices.T4
>
> Create two classes
>
> ```
> [DomainServiceClientCodeGenerator(typeof(MyServicesEntityGenerator),"C#")]
> public class MyServicesClientCodeGenerator : CSharpClientCodeGenerator
> {
>     protected override EntityGenerator EntityGenerator
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             return new MyServicesEntityGenerator();
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> public class MyServicesEntityGenerator : CSharpEntityGenerator
> {
>     protected override void GenerateAttributes(IEnumerable<Attribute>attributes, bool forcePropagation)
>     {
>         List<Attribute> newAttributes = new List<Attribute>(attributes);
>         List<Attribute> regularExpressionAttributes = (from c in attributes where c.GetType() == typeof(RegularExpressionAttribute) select c).ToList();
>
>         newAttributes.RemoveAll(delegate(Attribute attr)
>                 {
>                     return attr.GetType() == typeof(RegularExpressionAttribute);
>                 });
>
>         base.GenerateAttributes(newAttributes, forcePropagation);
>
>         foreach (RegularExpressionAttribute item in regularExpressionAttributes)
>         {
>             base.Write(string.Format("[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute(@\"{0}\",
>             ErrorMessage=@\"{1}\")]\r\n",
>             item.Pattern, item.ErrorMessage));
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Now to hook it all up, in the Silverlight project file we need to tell
>   RIA to use our generator. We have to edit the Silverlight project and
>   add the following element inside the first PropertyGroup just after
>   LinkedServerProject (the order doesn't matter, I just say that as a
>   reference).
>
> ```
> <LinkedServerProject>..\RIAServicesLibrary.Web\RIAServicesLibrary.Web.csproj</LinkedServerProject>
> <RiaClientCodeGeneratorName>RIAServicesLibrary.Web.Helpers.MyServicesEntityGenerator</RiaClientCodeGeneratorName>
> ```

.

No matter what I try, I can't seem to resolve **DomainServiceClientCodeGenerator**

```
[DomainServiceClientCodeGenerator(typeof(MyServicesEntityGenerator),"C#")]
```

1. I got the Nuget package RIAServices.T4 Version 4.2.0,
2. Added the references in the server side service project to 
   **Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools.dll**     **Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools.TextTemplate.dll**
3. I've included the namespaces in the code

   ```
   using Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools;
   using Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools.TextTemplate.CSharpGenerators;
   using Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools.TextTemplate;
   ```

Digging through the namespaces, all I can find is **DomainServiceClientCodeGeneratorAttribute** and **IDomainServiceClientCodeGenerator**

Can anyone tell me how to resolve my missing **DomainServiceClientCodeGenerator** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working. The project needed reference to 
**System.ComponentModel.Composition**

This key piece of information came from http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2010/10/28/RiaServicesT4WalkUp.aspx

> You’ll notice that I needed to add a reference to
>   Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Tools for this to work.  That
>   assembly is in our framework (not the Toolkit) and it’s where the
>   DomainServiceClientCodeGeneratorAttribute class is defined.  Also, in
>   order for this to compile, I needed to add a reference to
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition (MEF) because that attribute class
>   actually derives from ExportAttribute.

...

(for anyone wondering, this did not solve the MatchTimeoutInMilliseconds bug for me)

Answer (score 5):

I spent about 4 hours in order to get working **Silverlight 5 + Ria Services SP1** project created in **Visual Studio 2012 + Windiws 7 + .NET Framework 4** in **Visual Studio 2015 + Windows 10** in order to fix this error.

Initially I could not get it working in **Visual Studio 2015** at all.

So I installed **Visual Studio 2013 (Complete Type Installation) + Service Pack 5** and I get less errores.

After this I installed all old **Silverlight** stuff like **WPF Toolkit** and after this I just opened solution and unique error was about

> silverlight MatchTimeoutInMilliseconds bug : resolve
>   DomainServiceClientCodeGenerator

So without extra changes of the project properties I installed **.Net Framework 4.6.2 Preview**

> AND THIS ERROR GONE!!!

I compiled fine this solution and after this I was able to compile it under **Visual Studio 2015.**

I hope the time I spent will help to someone.