# Silverlight web service update fails to import wsdl

Tags: c#, web-services, silverlight, wsdl

We've been battling with a strange issue for a couple of days now. Have searched the net for answers but none seem to solve the error.

Our scenario is: our organization has a Silverlight 5 application, which was developed in VS 2010, and everything was working fine. It is actually running in our production servers.
Recently we migrated our development machines to VS 2015, and the machines themselves (new ones for the dept). The OS is Windows 7, same as before.

At first we were welcomed with that nasty [MatchTimeoutInMilliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662674/silverlight-matchtimeoutinmilliseconds-bug-resolve-domainserviceclientcodegene) error, due to the MS Framework. Eventually MS released the 4.6.2 Preview version which covered this issue.

Ok. So back to implementing the changes requested, we created a new method in our webservice, and it complied just fine. We do have the `[OperationContract]` and `[DataContract]` tags in place.  There is a question posted and answered with the justification that these tags were missing.
However, when we go to the SL app and update the WS reference, we get this "Custom tool error: Failed to generate code for the service reference ..."
Custom Tool Warning messages include
"Cannot import wsdl:binding..."
"Cannot import wsdl:port..."
"Cannot import wsdl:portType..."
"No endpoints compatible with Silverlight 5 were found. The generated client class will not be usable unless endpoint information is provided via the constructor."

We're puzzled, because then we thought we might have done something wrong, so we rolled back the changes, and updated the service reference with no changes, and we get the same error. The Referece.cs file is generated with no code, and all references to the webservice are no longer recognized by the compiler.

We've also read some posts that offer as a solution unchecking "Reuse types in referenced assemblies". Doing that does clear these errors, only to generate others, since our app was built on this premise.
We've also tried deleting the service reference and adding it back again, but to no avail.

Eventually we reverted the SL app to the point it was compiling, which was before updating the webservice reference, republished the WS with the new method, and manually added the new method to the Reference.cs file, tested it and it works.

This, however, should not be -the- solution. It's a hassle and prone to errors.
We'd appreciate any help in solving this matter, or an insight as to why this is happening.

thanks

Comment: Is your service protected by authentication?

Comment: No. It's plain and runs on the same machine

Comment: Well I am a little stumped then, because I did the same I had a vs2010 although I gone through 2013 but moved to 2015 and not encountered this. I havent however moved to 4.6.2 im on 4.5 because I could :P

Comment: Ok. I missed that. We had 2013 installed too, but that was on the older machines, and we never did edit this project with VS 2013. We had to install 4.6.2 preview because we were having trouble with that MatchTimeOutInMilliseconds.

Comment: I'm really wondering if we're doing something wrong, or if there was a flaw with the machine's setup, or if this is being generated by the .net framework, since MS discontinued SL, and all...

Comment: It sounds like it didnt build service correctly first, or, that it lost some of the settings for importing the service.  thats a regex issue right?  my silverlight app still lives.. so, Id go with there is hope, I must admit I was truly disappointed they dropped it as I found it way nicer to work with than asp.net ... much more like writing standard apps..

Comment: Yes. I've added a link to the post where I found the answer to that issue. I'd admit the service had not been built correctly, but the same happens with the old service build... I tried pointing the ref to the production ws, which was built long ago, and I get the same thing. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole problem is that, for some reason I still haven't found, VS fails to generate the code for **Reference.cs**.

As a workaround, we've managed to generate the Reference.cs file by using the **SlSvcUtil.exe** tool, located (on my machine) at "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Tools".

In order to get the same code as the one generated before the migration, I've used the following command and options:

SlSvcUtil.exe *my_ws_address* /namespace:"*,*my_class_namespace*" /ct:System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1 /r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v5.0\System.Windows.dll" /edb /ser:Auto

I didn't use the /out switch, but rather ran the command on my desired output directory. But you might want to look into that switch before running the command.